# Transaction error while yum install

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 from install of openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 from install of openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 from install of openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/ldap.conf.5.gz from install of openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/ldif.5.gz from install of openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `openldap24` package installed from the `ius` repo which is conflicting with the stock CentOS 6 `openldap` package.

You need to remove one or the other of those packages (the one from `ius` might be easier to remove).

Comment: yum remove openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: You don't use a full rpm name to yum remove. Try just `yum remove openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius`.

Comment: its the same result Etan

Comment: [root@nmappserver ~]# yum remove openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: also when i try removing the centos one its giving lot of dependencies....[root@nmappserver ~]# rpm -e openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
        ldif2ldbm is needed by (installed) migrationtools-47-7.el6.noarch
        liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by (installed) GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64
        liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-ldap-0:2.3.10-1.el6.x86_64
        liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by (installed) samba4-libs-0:4.0.0-58.el6.rc4.x86_64

Comment: Just try `yum remove openldap24`. Assuming you have it installed. It is possible you don't and the problem is that it is being pulled in as a requirement of some other package you are installing. What command did you run originally that encountered this problem?

Comment: i have removed it using the above command but when i try to install openldap again am getting below error yum install openldap*
Examining openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm: openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: [root@nmappserver ~]# rpm -qa | grep ldap*
nss-pam-ldapd-0.7.5-18.2.el6_4.x86_64
python-ldap-2.3.10-1.el6.x86_64
openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
php-ldap-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
apr-util-ldap-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64
pam_ldap-185-11.el6.x86_64
ldapjdk-4.18-6.el6.x86_64

Comment: the issue started when i removed openldap rpms using rpm -e --nodpes...then yum was not working, then installed openldap rpm after downlaoding it

Comment: `yum install openldap*` is only a reasonable command if you have openldap rpms in the current directory, do you? That `rpm` output says you have `openldap24` installed still. **Never** run `rpm -e --nodeps` it is virtually **never** what you actually want and lets you **horribly** break your system.

Comment: how can i remove the openldap24 ..i tried yum remove but its not getting removed

Comment: What happened when you ran `yum remove openldap24`? I'm assuming it complained about dependencies for other packages? You might need to use `yum shell` to set up a transaction to remove `erase openldap24` and `install openldap` in the same transaction.

Comment: > erase openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64
Setting up Remove Process
but nothing happens after this

Comment: [root@nmappserver ~]# rpm -qa | grep ldap*
openldap24-2.4.32-2.ius.el6.x86_64

Comment: The commands you run in the yum shell build up a transaction you need to use `transaction run` to actually execute the transaction (and possibly `transaction solve` first to run the dependency solver, but that might be automatic on `run` I'm not sure I don't use the shell often). The point is you can manually specify packages to install and remove at the same time to handle some tricky cases.